# Why getting error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, winforms

I have a web asp API which is returning value in the following format:

> {"idDoc":18,"idDocRipristino":0,"relCau":1,"numDoc":"2","data":"2016-10-17T00:00:00","relTavolo":3,"apertura":"4","orario":"2016-10-17T00:00:00","idAna":0,"nominativo":"5","relOpe":6,"totale":7.0,"note":"8","idAsp":0,"romana":0,"relOpe_Port":0}

And I'm using the below code from a winform Application to bind the data with devexpress gridview but I'm getting below error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'WinFormVB.Documenti[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Here is my winform code to access the API and reading the data using JSON:

```
      Async Sub GetDocumenti(idDoc As Integer)
    Dim Uri As String = "http://localhost:53917/api/Documenti/GetByIdDoc"
    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Using response = Await client.GetAsync([String].Format("{0}/{1}", Uri, idDoc))
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim DocumentisonData = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                GridCtrlDocumenti.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Documenti())(DocumentisonData).ToList()
            Else
                Dim result = DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Sorry no data found!!", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is my Repository :

```
    public DocumentiModel GetByIdDoc(int id)
    {
        using (var dbCtx = new USDevEntities())
        {
            var documenti = dbCtx.Documentis.Where(x => x.IDDoc == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (documenti != null)
            {
                return ConvertTo(documenti);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me how do I solve this error. Thanks.

Comment: The json is just a single object, yet you try to serialize it as an array.

Comment: I'm very new in JSON could you please give me an example to solve my issue or illustrate your answer?

Comment: Please show the `Documenti` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON represents a single object, while your code is trying to deserialize into an array.  That won't work.

Change this line:

```
GridCtrlDocumenti.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Documenti())(DocumentisonData).ToList()
```

To this:

```
Dim list As List(Of Documenti) = New List(Of Documenti)
list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Documenti)(DocumentisonData))
GridCtrlDocumenti.DataSource = list
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Absolutely you saved my hours. +1